# How to set time limit for waiting internet Connection in android AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-internet

I have use The AsyncTask For connecting Internet. a **Progress dialog** can show at onPreExecute() and i check is Online of that mobile if yes means it will execute the http connections code also dismiss the progress dialog at onPostExecute() and its work as good.

But i have problem if net connection is available at time of **Request** and connection closed before get **Response** means the Progress dialog showing always.

Now i want solve this if interconnect disconnect before get Response mean it's alert me as No internet connection and dismiss the progress dialog (may **set loading time limit for 30 seconds**).

below is my code.

can any one help?

```
   public class SubjectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Loading",
                "Please wait...");
        //checkConnection();

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        if (isOnline()) {  //using ConnectivityManager And Network Info

            try {

                //Http Request connections

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return 1;
        } else {

            alert("Check your internet connection");
            return 0;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcast receiver to get the event of network connect or disconnect. register this receiver in doInbackground method and unregister it in onPostExecute method.

```
 broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


                            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                            //Play with the info about current network state
                             if(info.getState()== NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
                               // hide loader and show alert here
}

                        }

                    }
                };

                intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
                registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the connection will be closed before or while the http request an `IOException` will be thrown. Catch that exception and close your Dialog there and inform the user about this event.

```
  if (isOnline()) {  //using ConnectivityManager And Network Info

        try {

            //Http Request connections

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Do the error handling here

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
  }
```

I don't know if you really need a return value to your onPostExecute(). If yes consder to make the logic aware that an exception could occur.

Answer (score 0):

i thank to Steve Benettand Bhawna Raheja,
sorry for the late reply,
Simply i have solve this error by set Timeout via **HttpRequest.TimeOut** .
i dont know how i forgot to set time out.

One again thank to You both.